# sumproduct if a cell contains a certain value, give all results otherwise just the specified result

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, sumproduct

My issue is that I need to reference a cell (A1) which will either be the name of a state that can be found in column L, or it can be "All States" which I then want to include all results of column L. I can't work out how to include this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IF(A1="All States",Data!$L:$L,Data!$L:$L=A1)),Data!Q:Q)
```

I want to add a bunch more criteria based on the above so I don’t want to go down the route of imbedding the sumproduct in an if function because the formula will quickly become too unweildy.

Comment: providing sample records here would help people in answering your question.

Comment: Basically it looks like you are trying to get the corresponding value from column Q, or the some of column q.  Is it possible to a a state to column L called All States and in column Q use sum of all the cells above?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of choices.  Using your initial formula I would tweak it to

```
(A)  =SUMPRODUCT((IF($A$1="All States",1,($L$2:$L$11=$A$1)))*($Q$2:$Q$11))
```

But this would need to be entered as an array formula so instead of just confirming with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you need <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You will know you have done it right when { } show up around your formula.  Note that they cannot be added manually.

A non array type formula which would be faster I believe would be to look at your two options.  You are either dealing with a single state or all states.  Set up an `IF` check to determine if you need to sum all of column Q, or if you need to find a single value from column Q.  I used the following formula:

```
(B)  =IF(A1="all states",SUM($Q$2:$Q$11),INDEX($Q$2:$Q$11,MATCH($A$1,$L$2:$L$11,0)))
```

A bit of a cheat but but simplifies things, is to add a final state to the bottom of your list in L and call is "All States".  In the corresponding row in Q place `=sum(First Cell:Last Cell)`.  If you do that then you can use the following formula:

```
(C)  =SUMPRODUCT(($L$2:$L$12=$A$1)*($Q$2:$Q$12))
```

That are other options out there as well, just thought I would show some options.

[image: Proof of concept]